# Using Python for loop to take rolling sum product

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use a for loop to calculate the trailing sum product of a list of values, and a reverse counter. That is, at each iteration of the loop, the current value would be multiplied by 1, the previous value would be multiplied by 2, and so on back to n values, where n is the number of values between the start of the list and the current iteration.

The below screenshot shows how I would do this in Excel using SUMPRODUCT:

[SUMPRODUCT in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I04AE.jpg)

In Python, I am able to use cumsum from Numpy to return the rolling cumulative sum of the list of values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [8,6,7,5,9]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['values'])
values=df['values']

test=[]
for x, index in enumerate(values):
    test.append(np.cumsum(values)[x])
```

I am also able to use the below to get a reversed counter, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this into the first for loop, and I'm not sure how to get the reverse counter to reset to 1 at each iteration:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(values))):
    print(i+1)
```

What is the most straightforward way to get the counter to reset at each iteration of the loop, and to incorporate it into a trailing sumproduct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So are you basically after `(df['values'] * range(len(df), 0, -1)).sum()` ?

Comment: shorter `test = np.cumsum(values).tolist()`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Better show what result values you want to get. Maybe it can be done without `for`-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonClements suggested you may need simple

```
(df['values'] * range(len(df), 0, -1)).sum()
```

without any `for`-loop

if you need partial result then you can get part of rows ie. `sub_df = df[:3]`

```
sub_df = df[:3]
(sub_df['values'] * range(len(sub_df), 0, -1)).sum()
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = [8, 6, 7, 5, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['values'])

size = 3
sub_df = df[:size]
#result = (sub_df['values'] * range(len(sub_df), 0, -1)).sum()
result = (sub_df['values'] * range(size, 0, -1)).sum()
print(f'result [{size}]: {result}')

size = 4
sub_df = df[:size]
#result = (sub_df['values'] * range(len(sub_df), 0, -1)).sum()
result = (sub_df['values'] * range(size, 0, -1)).sum()
print(f'result [{size}]: {result}')
```

Result:

```
result [3]: 43
result [4]: 69
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to put all in DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

data = [8, 6, 7, 5, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['values'])

# ---

size = 3
sub_df = df[:size]
result = (sub_df['values'] * range(size, 0, -1)).sum()
print(f'result [{size}]: {result}')

df['counter C'] = ''  # default value
df.loc[:size-1, 'counter C'] = range(size, 0, -1)
df['result C'] = ''  # default value
df.loc[size-1,'result C'] = result
   
# ---

size = 4
sub_df = df[:size]
result = (sub_df['values'] * range(size, 0, -1)).sum()
print(f'result [{size}]: {result}')

df['counter D'] = ''  # default value
df.loc[:size-1, 'counter D'] = range(size, 0, -1)
df['result D'] = ''  # default value
df.loc[size-1, 'result D'] = result

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   values counter C result C counter D result D
0       8         3                  4         
1       6         2                  3         
2       7         1       43         2         
3       5                            1       69
4       9
```

Comment: I ended up modifying @JonClements suggestion (which yielded a single sum as a result) to return an array of values: `test=[] for x,index in enumerate(values): x=x+1 test.append((values[0:x] * range(x, 0, -1)).sum())` This produces a list where each element is the trailing sumproduct of the preceding values and the reverse counter, starting from 1 at the current element and then increasing by 1 as the loop moves backwards.

The end result that you get is [8,22,43,69,104].